# c++ function with optional arguments

Tags: c++

What is the best way to declare a method like this:

```
calc( string name, string arguments, 
      string lib, 
      string &output, string &error, 
      string finishInfo )
```

where every parameter is optional? User can pass name, arguments and error if needed; pass only finishInfo or pass all six arguments. Probably the most user friendly is being able to call:

```
calc( "my name", , "my library", , , );
```

but I don't know if it's possible to do without boost. I cannot overload, because I'd need to create 62 methods. My best idea is:

```
calc( string * name = NULL, string * arguments = NULL, 
      string * lib = NULL, 
      string * output = NULL, string * error = NULL, 
      string * finishInfo = NULL )
```

I'm changing everything to pointers, this way we need to call

```
calc( ptr_myName, NULL, ptr_myLib, NULL, NULL, NULL );
```

or

```
calc( string name = "", string arguments = "",
      string lib = "",
...
calc( "", "",
      "my library",
```

Comment: Why not just let the user pass an empty string?

Comment: you *can* have an argument default be default-constructed.

Comment: [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) sounds like a good fit (or, of course, its `boost::optional` doppelgänger).

Comment: You're starting to get into territory where creating an argument struct might be a good idea. User sets data in the struct, then passes the struct to the function. This can make calls like `NULL, ptr_myLib, NULL, NULL, NULL` more legible, and helps them get the order correct if they can assign to a named variable in a struct instead.

Comment: i would suggest to create a class with these argument as members of the class. and pass the class to yur function. This way, it will be more cleaner code.

Comment: You may look at [Named_parameters](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Named_parameters#C.2B.2B) (which are not supported natively in C++ but can be emulated).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My experience with many arguments of the same type is that it quickly becomes a frustrating and unreadable mess as I try to remember their order. Other languages like Python have the option to name a parameter as you pass it into the function, but unfortunately we do not have such pleasantries in C++

A nice workaround is an argument struct. With public variables (or equivalent getter/setter functions, but I haven't usually found that to be necessary), the end user can set the desired fields in a legible manner before passing the struct into the function:

For example:

```
struct calc_args
{
   string name;
   string arguments;
   string finish_info;
   string output; // out arg
   string finishInfo; // out arg
};

void calc(calc_args& arguments)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: The nice part about `std::string` here is that its default ctor will already give you an empty string if you don't want to set it. If you need another value, you can use the in-class member initialization feature that comes with C++11

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion will be to use a `std::map<std::string, std::string>` as your input.

```
calc(std::map<std::string, std::string> const& args) { ... }
```

Then, you are free to pass whatever you can.

You can use

```
calc({{"name", "my name"}, {"lib", "my library"}});
calc({{"lib", "my library"}});
```

Comment: As an added benefit, the parameters will be named. Something handy, in a function with all optional arguments of identical type.

Comment: Its a great, clean solution, but as I understand user would need to know names of the parameters beforehand, maybe as a comment in a header file.

Comment: @JoshThunar, yes, that will be needed.

Comment: `std::map<MyEnum, std::string>` would even be better as it avoids typo in variable name.

Answer (score 0):

As a relevant point of interest, variadic templates could work here:

```
template <typename T>
T DoStuff (T t) //Base case
{
  //do stuff..
  return t;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
T DoStuff(T t, Args... args) //Recursive case
{
  return DoStuff(t + args...); 
}

int main()
{
  DoStuff(1,2,3,4,5); //Output: 15
}
```

This allows you to pass an unknown number of parameters into a function and recursively operate upon each.

Comment: I think you meant to say `return t + DoStuff(args...); `

Comment: Actually it took me a minute to decipher why your actual output is 31 and not 15 if you say `DoStuff(t + args...)` and that's because what's happening is you are first adding 1 to each of (2, 3, 4, 5), which creates a new pack of (3, 4, 5, 6), to which 3 is added to each to obtain (7, 8, 9), to which 7 is added to get (15, 16), which then returns 31.